# How to line break with flex-shrink in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to develop a chat-like system, using this sample.

https://www.bootdey.com/snippets/view/white-chat

I replaced `<input type="text">` with `<textarea>`, because messages are usually composed with multi-lines.

I want to display messages with line-breaks. But I couldn't. Does `flex-shrink` cause problem?

For example, When I typed this in the textarea, ↓

```
Hello
    World
```

the message is displayed like this. ↓

```
Hello World
```

I expect the same as line-breaks as the textarea input. ↓

```
Hello
    World
```

I added this style to `<div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 mr-3">`

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

But the messages' display did not change.

Please tell me how to line break in this situation.

----------------------------------------------------------ps

Without `flex-shrink`, the displayed message was like this ↓
The result didn't change. So I understood `flex-shrink` was not the problem.

```
Hello World
```

Without `flex-shrink`, and with `white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;`, the displayed message was curious ↓

```
                                            Hello
World
```

I have no idea what is the problem.

Here is the HTML & CSS source.
https://www.bootdey.com/snippets/view/white-chat

Comment: Does it work without flex shrink? Easiest way to find out is to remove that flex shrink class

Comment: Probably going to need to see some code and/or a reduced test case.  When I added `style = "white-space:pre-wrap" to one of the bubbles on that linked page then added some newlines and spaces to the text, it worked.

Comment: Which tag and CSS Selector did you add `white-space: pre-wrap;` to?  I added to `<div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 ml-3">`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try flex-shrink in css file like this

```
flex-shrink: 8;
```

Replece 8 with your desired value

Comment: I replaced `flex-shrink: 0;` with `flex-shrink: 8;`, but It doesn't work...